# jQuery: wait for slide to finish before executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wait the sliding animation is done before executing the code, as shown below:

```
$('#blueimp-gallery').on('slide', function (event, index, slide) {
    $(this).find('.modal-citation')
        .text($('#links a').eq(index).data('citation'));
});
```

I've tried a few ways of doing this, but none of them worked.

```
$('#blueimp-gallery').on('slide', function (event, index, slide) {
    $(this).find('.modal-citation')
        .text($('#links a').eq(index).data('citation')).delay(3000); // didn't work
});

$('#blueimp-gallery').on('slide', function (event, index, slide) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-citation')
        .text($('#links a').eq(index).data('citation')); // didn't work
    }, 1000);
});
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: What library/plugin are you using for the slide? It might be worth creating a codepen.io example.

Comment: The callback function doesn't execute until the initial function is complete. You should not need the setTimeout at all.

Comment: I'm using blueimp's Bootstrap Image Gallery.

Comment: i was writing the same comment when you posted yours! callback doesn't execute until the initial operation is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set this in the plugin options :

```
// Callback function executed after the slide change transition.
// Is called with the gallery instance as "this" object and the
// current index and slide as arguments:
onslideend: function() {
 // Do something
}
```

Taken from : https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#event-callbacks